# Android - Background service Timer/AlarmManager self-restarting

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, timertask

I have a function that sends location updates to my server and i need it to run all the time on set intervals. I know all processes can be killed by the system, but i need a way to make it restart by itself when killed. I know repeating event can be done either with Timer or AlarmManager, but which is better in my case, and how do i create a service that will be restarted if the system kills it? I'm beginner with android so please use detailed code/explanation.

This is the code i'm using to repeat my function now, but it gets killed when i close the application and if it's not killed, doubles the function so it sends two/three/four etc. updates every 5 minutes:

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
 timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
     public void run() {
          //do a barrel roll
     }
  }, 0, 300000);//repeat every 5 minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Send yourself a PendingIntent to start the service via an Alarm that you register with the AlarmManager. Note that an alarm can wake your process if its not awake (read the documentation for details)

### Start by reading the documentation @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: You can google this, these are basic things you need to know as a developer. You need to get to grips with the APIs that are provided. I promise you its not that complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's the correct one but i won't choose it as such, because i already did my research and read all these stuff and knew mostly what is required, BUT, like i mentioned, i am new to android and i didn't know how exactly it should be done, so i needed help with that. I've managed to build my app to do what is supposed to do properly, now, but i would still appreciate a good example from a professional.

Comment: @RaTre Sorry, Stackoverflow is **not** a code generation website. I provided the answer and I refuse to give you the flat out code if its not necessary. Please learn to read the documentation.